# Swift playground / new Algorithms Package - type '[Int]' has no member error

Tags: swift, package

What is wrong with my code that I'm receiving **value of type '[Int]' has no member 'combinations'** ?

```
import Cocoa
import Algorithms
let numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40]
for combo in numbers.combinations(ofCount: 2) {
    print(combo)
}
```

Comment: What do you expect? `[[10,10],[10,20][10,30],[10,40],[20,10],...,[40,40]]`? Where have you found this method?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265976/4172698 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/25166979/4172698 might help

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This is the package I'm trying to run: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-swift-packages-in-playgrounds/

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you solved this? @matthewmodine