# How to use reduce() on multidimensional arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to iterate through a multidimensional array and compare the elements with one another and increment a value if a condition is met

```
   var arrayExample = [[4,8],[15,30],[25,50]];

   var noOfSimiRect: Int = 0

   arrayExample.reduce(0) {
    
   let a = $0[0]      //error: Value of type 'int' has no subscripts
   let b = $0[1]      //error: Value of type 'int' has no subscripts
   let c = $1[0]      
   let d = $1[1]      

    
if a.isMultiple(of: c) && b.isMultiple(of: d) {
    noOfSimiRect += 1
    
}
}

print(noOfSimiRect)
```

Alternatively, if I used the following syntax, I am still getting the error  there

```
   var arrayExample = [[4,8],[15,30],[25,50]];
   var noOfSimiRect: Int = 0

   arrayExample.reduce(0) {
    
    let a = $0.0     //error: value of type 'int' has no member '0'
    let b = $1.0    //error: value of type 'int' has no member '1'
    let c = $0.0    //error: value of type '[int]' has no member 0'
    let d = $1.0     //error: value of type '[int]' has no member '1'
    
if a.isMultiple(of: c) && b.isMultiple(of: d) {
    noOfSimiRect += 1
    
}
}

 print(noOfSimiRect)
```

Thank you to David and Martin for answering my question but I found a catch in both your solutions.

var arrayExample = [[4,8],[15,30],[25,50]];

In the given array I want the following:

1. compare [4,8] with [15,30] and [25,50]
2. compare [15,30] with [4,8] and [25,50]
3. compare [25,50] with [4,8] and [15,30]

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465281/flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-swift

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to avoid using `$0` in a closure if you have issue understanding it. use real var, also it should help you see their type (if it's an int, cleary you won't be able to do `thatInt[someIndex]`, or `thatInt.0`. It doesn't make sense. I didn't understood what you want in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you misunderstand the inputs to the closure of `reduce`. The first input argument is the accumulating result, while the 2nd is the current element of the array. `$0` and `$1` are not the current and next elements of the array as you assume they are.

You need to iterate over the `indices` of the array to access 2 subsequent nested arrays and be able to check their elements against each other.

```
var noOfSimiRect: Int = 0
for index in arrayExample.indices.dropLast() {
    let current = arrayExample[index]
    let next = arrayExample[index + 1]
    
    if current[0].isMultiple(of: next[0]) && current[1].isMultiple(of: next[1]) {
        noOfSimiRect += 1
    }
}

print(noOfSimiRect)
```

Comment: In the given array I want the following:

compare [4,8] with [15,30] and [25,50]
compare [15,30] with [4,8] and [25,50]
compare [25,50] with [4,8] and [15,30]

Comment: @ilakk so are you trying to compare all possible combinations of 2 subarrays? You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51474264/4667835) answer for that

Comment: Thank you David. This is what I wanted!!